# PHP - stream_socket_client with tcp protocol using proxy with login and password

Tags: php, proxy

I want to make request with **stream_socket_client** but I need use proxy (and set port, login and password for successfull verity connect using my proxy address).
Is it possible to make this request? How I can do it?

I know, I can use something like this:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'tcp' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
        )
    )
   );
```

but how I can put login and password for authorise this proxy? And how I when I will logged, how I can use stream_socket_client with proxy?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean a http proxy? In that case I doubt it would accept a simple socket connection which isn't using the http protocol. If not, then what sort of proxy is it, what connections/protocols does it understand?

Comment: @ADyson I want make this script: `stream_socket_client("tcp://mx.wp.pl:25", $errno, $errstr, 15);` but from my main server this request return FALSE. When I try using this script on localhost (other IP address), I can do this request successfully. So how I can make this request using http/https proxy (with login and password auth)?

Comment: 25 is usually the SMTP port. Are you trying to connect to an email server, perhaps? If so, you can't forward SMTP traffic through a HTTP proxy...they are different protocols. Http proxies can forward http requests only.  It might help us to assist you if you explain the exact purpose of making this connection through your code

Comment: @ADyson I want to check if email address is correct. I use this script: https://www.codexworld.com/verify-email-address-check-if-real-exists-domain-php/ but from my main server this script in many cases return FALSE. When I try using this script on localhost (other IP address), I can do this request successfully. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I got: `Timed out while waiting for data! (timeout 5 seconds)
Timed out while waiting for data! (timeout 5 seconds)
Timed out while waiting for data! (timeout 5 seconds)
Timed out while waiting for data! (timeout 5 seconds)
421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 213.180.147.146 (213.180.147.146:25), connect error 10060
All connection fails
Email <koszula@vp.pl> is valid, but not exist!` but this email address exists (I created this account).

Comment: Well if it timed out it can't possibly test if the email is OK. I don't know if thats something the smtp server generated, or your own code, its not very clear. Anyway as I said above, you can't sent SMTP traffic through a http proxy. If you need to do this, ask your network administrator if they are happy to open the correct port outbound for you, or if there is another alternative approach they would consider to enable your overall goal

Comment: @ADyson thank's for your help. Every servers works fine but I have problem with vp.pl and wp.pl (example: jakubczak8321@wp.pl  - it's exist). Can you help me - if it's not problem with IP address - where is a problem?

Comment: Probably it's a firewall issue as I mentioned